# Comparing month and Year Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I need to fetch data between two dates but its not working.

my table-

[image]

from date and to date parameters are -

```
$from_date = '2016-12';
$to_date = '2017-03';
```

table column **Month** type is **varchar**

```
$this->db->select('*', FAlSE);
$this->db->where('t.Flag', '0');
$this->db->where('tpd.Status', $status);
$this->db->where("STR_TO_DATE(tpd.Month, '%Y-%m') >=", date($from_date));
$this->db->where("STR_TO_DATE(tpd.Month, '%Y-%m') <=", date($to_date));
$this->db->from('test_periodicity_details tpd');
$this->db->join('test t', 'tpd.Test_Id=t.Test_Id');
$this->db->join('school_information si', 't.School_Id=si.School_Id', 'left');
$this->db->join('test_status ss', 'tpd.Status=ss.Test_Status_Id', 'left');
echo $this->db->get_compiled_select();
$query = $this->db->get();
if ($query->num_rows() > 0){
    return $query->result();
}
else {
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have Solved The Query -

```
$this->db->select('*', FAlSE);
$this->db->where('t.Flag', '0');
$this->db->where('tpd.Status', $status);
$this->db->where('tpd.Month>=', date($from_date));
$this->db->where('tpd.Month<=', date($to_date));
$this->db->from('test_periodicity_details tpd');
$this->db->join('test t', 'tpd.Test_Id=t.Test_Id');
$this->db->join('school_information si', 't.School_Id=si.School_Id', 'left');
$this->db->join('test_status ss', 'tpd.Status=ss.Test_Status_Id', 'left');
//echo $this->db->get_compiled_select();
$query = $this->db->get();
if ($query->num_rows() > 0){
    return $query->result();
}
else {
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) returns a string, don't cast the month values to datetimes (with [STR_TO_DATE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)). The first parameter of [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) is the format string to output - the second parameter is the actual timestamp (date). So `date($from_date)` == `date('2016-12')` == `'2016-12'`. If you continue using STR_TO_DATE() then you would have a datetime value and a string value - while MySQL should be able to coalesce the values it is unnecessary.

You can use the [BETWEEN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) operator to compare the Month with the range of dates:

```
$this->db->where('tpd.Month BETWEEN \''.$from_date .'\' AND \''.$to_date.'\'');
```

Otherwise just replace the two WHERE condition calls with:

```
$this->db->where('tpd.Month>=', $from_date);
$this->db->where('tpd.Month<=', $to_date);
```

You can see the results of the updated queries in [this sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4b16f6/6). I also have an example of this working in PHP (but without CodeIgniter) on [this site](http://elliott.andrewz.org/data/periodicity.php). It is running the equivalent queries with [MySQLi functions](http://php.net/mysqli).